# Could collision of two black holes, each the mass of the moon, be a good probe for quantum gravity?

Tags: black-holes, collision, quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves

This is a naive question (to say the least), so I’m expecting another tsunami of downvotes :)

I’ve been learning about the “ultraviolet catastrophe”, and Planck’s solution to it, which theorizes that blackbody radiation doesn’t not grow exponentially with frequency, but instead peaks around the violet wavelength and then trails off.

Violet wavelength is ~ 450 nanometers.

Then, I started wondering, would a similar theory be valid for gravitational waves?

In other words, would we expect gravitons to behave like photons with respect to their radiation spectra?

My initial suspicion is that no, gravitational wave radiation will not behave like blackbody radiation, but figured I would ask anyway.

For a concrete example:

For 2 black holes of Mass the size of our sun, the smallest gravitational wave wavelength is a few kilometers (presumably close to the Schwarzchild radius of the black holes).

However, if you took 2 black holes the size of a small moon (about 10^19 kg), their Schwartzschild radius would be 14 nanometers.

[Wolfram Alpha calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2G*%281x10%5E19%20kg%29%2F%20%28Speed%20of%20light%29%5E2)

Presumably they would be radiating gravitational waves at a wavelength < 100 nanometers in the final moments before merging.

(If gravitational waves *were* to behave like blackbody radiation, then we would expect more gravitons to be emitted at lower frequencies than at the higher frequencies.)

(I have similar questions about gluons and muons, but that would be for another time)

Comment: Personal theories generally are closed as off topic.

Comment: LOL. First find two black holes the size of the moon.

Comment: Yes I’m still trying to get an intuitive sense for Plancks solution to the ultraviolet catastrophe, by studying here: https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Materials_Science/Supplemental_Modules_(Materials_Science)/Electronic_Properties/Solving_the_Ultraviolet_Catastrophe

Comment: Planck theorized that ( E=hc/wavelength ) for photons.  I guess my most general question is: Does the same equation apply to all things that move at or very near the speed of light?

Comment: More precisely does ( E=hc/wavelength ) apply to all bosons?  Or is it correct to say E = (hc/wavelength) + (mc^2) ?

Comment: It probably makes no sense to think of a 2 moon binary system as being in “gravitational equilibrium”... in the same sense that a blackbody is in “thermodynamic equilibrium”.

Comment: I don’t know of any reason to expect the gravitational radiation from the collision to have a blackbody (actually, graybody) spectrum like Hawking radiation does.

Comment: I would expect the radiation to be primarily at twice the orbital frequency if we are talking about an inspiraling binary, just like for stellar-mass black holes, and dropping off rapidly at higher frequencies. Until the holes get to within a few radii of each other, the usual non-relativistic quadrupole approximation should give the spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your overall question: yes, thermally gravitons are expected to behave (in a first, exceedingly accurate approximation) just like photons. This is because gravitons, as much as photons, are massless bosons, and all the massless bosons (provided that they can be treated approximately as non-interacting particles) possess the same blackbody spectrum. Moreover, $E=\hbar\omega$ holds for any kind of massless particle (be it a boson or a fermion).

Just to be clear, when we speak of gravitons we usually interpret these as weak perturbations of the gravitational field. As such, all the complications due to the strong non-linearity of the Einstein equations do not arise in the context of gravitons, just by definition.

However, I must point out that several (more or less explicit) assumptions in your question were wrong, and this leads to much confusion in answering. First of all no, blackbody radiation does not peak around the wavelength of violet. This is because the peak of the blackbody spectrum actually depends on temperature through Wien's law,

$$
\lambda_{\text{peak}}=\frac{2.898 \cdot 10^{-3}\ \text{m}\cdot\text{K}}{T}
$$

Therefore the higher the temperature, the shorter the wavelength of the peak. If the temperature is sufficiently low then the peak will occur in the infrared or radio portion of the spectrum, while if the temperature is sufficiently high the peak will occur well beyond the visible (and indeed its wavelength can be arbitrarily short at increasing temperature).

Second of all, colliding black holes (or neutron stars, or whatever) are not expected to emit gravitational radiation with the blackbody spectrum. Indeed, the spectrum of the gravitational radiation emitted in a collision depends on the kinematic of the collision (mainly the masses of the bodies and their relative angular momentum), with no reference, for example, on temperature. So no, quantum effects cannot be explored in a collision through the mechanism of blackbody radiation, since there is not any in the sense that I believe you are implying. Nonetheless, it is believed by some that quantum effects may be detectable through the radiation spectrum of a collision.

On the other hand, black holes are indeed expected to emit radiation with the blackbody spectrum, in the form of Hawking radiation. Here the actual, thermal temperature is replaced by Hawking's temperature

$$
T_{H}=\frac{\hbar c^{3}}{8\pi G \kappa_{B}M}
$$

which is just a measure of the inverse mass $M$ of the black hole. In particular, since the power of the emitted radiation goes like $T_{H}^{4}\propto M^{-4}$, this kind of radiation is very faint, unless the black hole is quite small. However, this kind of radiation is not gravitonic: all kind of particles are emitted in the Hawing process. Hawking radiation is a strong candidate phenomenon for the study of quantum gravity.

Some sidenotes. For massive particles one has $E=\sqrt{m^{2}c^{4}+p^{2}c^{2}}=\sqrt{m^{2}c^{4}+h^{2}c^{2}/\lambda^{2}}$ to replace the formula $E=hc/\lambda$, which is valid in the limit $m\to 0$. Muons do not behave like photons, first of all because they are massive, second of all because they are fermions and last of all because they are unstable particles. Gluons also do not behave like photons, but this time this is due to their interactions: at low temperatures they are confined and cannot be detected (in particular they do not have a blackbody spectrum), and they become unconfined and approximately non-interacting at very high temperatures, in conditions which are not easy to find in our visible universe (perhaps in the inner core of neutron stars, or early on in the very first instants after the Big Bang).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!  It’s encouraging, at the very least, to read that “E=hw” is expected to hold for gravitons.  When I do searches for papers that attempt to explore this phenomena, I come across extremely dense papers like this https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0311065.pdf.  I think a next step for me  is to understand perturbation theory better.

Comment: In the article you cited what they are studying is the correction to the dispersion relation $E^{2}=m^{2}+|\vec{p}|^{2}$ for a scalar particle (not for the graviton!) due to the presence of a thermal bath of gravitons, as mediated by the gravitational interaction. This is not a quantum-gravitational effect per se, as much as a thermal effect, in the sense that any kind of interaction (electromagnetic, strong, etc.) would induce a similar modification of the dispersion relation at non-zero temperatures.

Comment: Then there can be corrections to the dispersion relation which do not vanish at zero temperature (see eg. eq.(1) in the article). These are due to truly quantum gravitational effects, which in general one does not know how to compute analytically. In high-curvature regions of the universe, these may be non-negligible. Nonetheless, for most purposes our universe can be though of as a flat spacetime. Here $E=hc/\lambda$ holds to an exceptionally good approximation, that breaks down only at momenta of the order of the Planck energy ($E_{P}\sim 10^{16}$ TeV).

Comment: Finally, I forgot about expansion. Actually, the expansion of our universe does modify the dispersion relation $E=hc/\lambda$ to $E=hc a(t)/\lambda(t)$, where $a(t)$ is the expansion factor at the cosmological time $t$. You should really read the former as $\lambda(t)=hca(t)/E$, where $E=h\nu$ is a constant: it is the wavelength that changes with time at fixed energy/frequency.
Nonetheless, this is not quite a quantum-gravitational effect: in terms of the frequency, rather than of the energy, the factor of $h$ disappears, and indeed the equation can be derived in classical general relativity.

Comment: First, I need to understand better how gravitons would have a “temperature”.  Second, it seems like high frequency gravitational waves with nanometer scale wavelengths would be, like you say, only produced in Big Bang, and then redshifted to very low frequency.  The LIGO and LISA experiments only search for *very* low frequency waves.  Nonetheless, it seems like high frequency waves could be explored.  Maybe they have been, but there’s not much current literature on them.

Comment: Ok I found a paper with a ton of examples, which is somewhat easier to digest here.  This is the sort of detail I’m looking for, and it’s written at a level I can understand :) intended for the Navy :) https://fas.org/irp/agency/dod/jason/gravwaves.pdf

Comment: Great! Also, if you liked the answer don't forget to upvote/accept!